# conf files in hadoop book examples

Tags: hadoop

I am gettng started with hadoop, installed the 1.1.1 release and ran example 5-3 in "Definitive guide to hadoop".
 It did print out some configuration properties but I am not able to find those xml files in the hadoop installation or the example code.

The following code assumes that the xml files added to configuration exist somewhere but I cant find them.

EDIT: mapred-site.xml & hdfs-site.xml are in the conf folder of hadoop installation but they are empty. So I dont think its using them.

After building the book examples I go to the chap 5 directory containg ch-05.jar and run the follwing command : $asd> hadoop jar ch05-3.0.jar ConfigurationPrinter

```
public class ConfigurationPrinter extends Configured implements Tool {
static {
Configuration.addDefaultResource("hdfs-default.xml");
Configuration.addDefaultResource("hdfs-site.xml");
Configuration.addDefaultResource("mapred-default.xml");
Configuration.addDefaultResource("mapred-site.xml");
}
@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration conf = getConf();
for (Entry<String, String> entry: conf) {
System.out.printf("%s=%s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
return 0;
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new ConfigurationPrinter(), args);
System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would find {core|mapred|hdfs}-default files in your hadoop-core-X.X.jar .

Comment: What you say makes sense but in the hadoop book it says "If you omit the -conf option, then you pick up the Hadoop configuration in the conf subdirectory under $HADOOP_INSTALL" . I did try and specify -conf $HADOOP_INSTALL/conf but it still picks it from somewhere else.